# Power door lock failure when engine is off

Tags: power, locks, door, audio

I have a 2003 Honda Civic ex sedan and recently the power door lock stopped working. I can manually lock and unlock all the doors and when I turn my engine on and start driving I can use the power door lock, although sometimes it only works to unlock the doors. This problem recently popped out of the blue shortly after I developed stereo and amp power failure problems (still not receiving power atm even though i replaced all fuses and checked all the grounds). Is there any correlation between the 2 power failures? Any suggestions for either problem? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the wiring diagram for the car? Many of the Chilton type manuals will have one. If not there, sometimes you can find them online. Without knowing how the stereo was wired, it would be very hard to answer this question. If you follow the wires back from the stereo, can you find which fuse they are on?

Comment: There might be a relay that turns on those accessories when the ignition is on. Also there maybe be a secondary fuse panel with or near your relays under the hood. The manual might tell you where they are.

Comment: I'd check the wire harness that goes into the driver door those wires are prone to stretching and breaking. And would account for the weird power lock issue.

Comment: I'd bet the body control module is fried.